# Bibleref: different styles in text and in index

Tags: indexing, bibleref

Is it possible to have full text style in document and short style in index?
Moving `\biblerefstyle{jerusalem}` before `printindex` changes whole document

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % see geometry.pdf on how to lay out the page. There's lots.
\geometry{a4paper} % or letter or a5paper or ... etc
%\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[protestant,text]{bibleref-french}
%\biblerefstyle{jerusalem}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\ibibleverse{Gn}

\ibibleverse{Ex}

\ibibleverse{Lv}

\ibibleverse{Nb}

\ibibleverse{Dt}

\ibibleverse{Jos}

\ibibleverse{Jg}

\ibibleverse{IS}

\ibibleverse{IIS}

\ibibleverse{IR}

\ibibleverse{IIR}

\ibibleverse{ICh}

\ibibleverse{IICh}

\ibibleverse{Esd}

\ibibleverse{Ne}

\ibibleverse{IM}

\ibibleverse{IIM}

\ibibleverse{Is}

\ibibleverse{Es}

\ibibleverse{Jr}

\ibibleverse{Ez}

\ibibleverse{Os}

\ibibleverse{Jl}

\ibibleverse{Am}

\ibibleverse{Ab}

\ibibleverse{Jon}

\ibibleverse{Mi}

\ibibleverse{Na}

\ibibleverse{So}

\ibibleverse{Ha}

\ibibleverse{Ag}

\ibibleverse{Za}

\ibibleverse{Ml}

\ibibleverse{Dn}

\ibibleverse{Jb}

\ibibleverse{Pr}

\ibibleverse{Qo}

\ibibleverse{Ct}

\ibibleverse{Rt}

\ibibleverse{Lm}

\ibibleverse{Est}

\ibibleverse{Tb}

\ibibleverse{Jdt}

\ibibleverse{Ba}

\ibibleverse{Sg}

\ibibleverse{Si}

\ibibleverse{Ps}

\ibibleverse{Ps}(18:)

\ibibleverse{Ps}(18:)-(19:)

\ibibleverse{Mt}

\ibibleverse{Lc}

\ibibleverse{Jn}

\ibibleverse{Mc}

\ibibleverse{Ac}

\ibibleverse{Rm}

\ibibleverse{ICo}

\ibibleverse{IICo}

\ibibleverse{Ga}

\ibibleverse{Ep}

\ibibleverse{Ph}

\ibibleverse{Col}

\ibibleverse{ITh}

\ibibleverse{IITh}

\ibibleverse{ITm}

\ibibleverse{IITm}

\ibibleverse{Tt}

\ibibleverse{Phm}

\ibibleverse{He}

\ibibleverse{Jc}

\ibibleverse{IP}

\ibibleverse{IIP}

\ibibleverse{IJn}

\ibibleverse{IIJn}

\ibibleverse{IIIJn}

\ibibleverse{Jude}

\ibibleverse{Ap}    

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: The style of citation in index is determined not when using `\printindex` , but when using ibibleverse. (look on the .idx file). So using `\biblerefstyle` before `\printindex` won't change anything. You should open an issue for a new feature of bibleref (but I won't have time before anytime)